# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near "="

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I try am trying to build a function that populates a table when given the name of the table and what parameter to order it by.

I think I am just making a syntax error in my SQL command but I can't find it. Please help.

```
public DataTable populateTable(string tableName, string orderByParameter)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM (value = @tbl) ORDER BY (parameter = @obp) DESC";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = cmdString;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl", tableName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obp", orderByParameter);
            using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                ad.Fill(table);
            }
        }
        try

        {
            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            return table;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have variables in table name or in 'order by' clause.

You could build the query dynamically as:

```
string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "] ORDER BY " + orderByParameter +" DESC";
```

With this you won't need to add the parameters `@tbl` and `@obp` to the command.

Note that this runs into SQL injection related vulnerabilities. So you shouldn't do this unless you are absolutely certain that the table with given name exists, and the `orderByParameter` is a valid expression.

Comment: Thank you for relieving my head scratching for the night.